# React Native : How to find Screen awake time between Sleeps

Tags: react-native, sleep, resume

I`m creating an Application that tracks the **Screen awake time**. How to get the **Screen awake time** and to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppState. Read here the official [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate)

Comment: AppState is all about the state of the App, whether its in background or active. i want to track the device state. thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @sachinsachu i also want the screen usage time. so let me know if you get something in react native to get scrren time.